# How to show data on Jasper with having more than one rows

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports

Need one help. Suppose:

I have one query which gives 3 rows as output once user submits form.

On the same table 3 rows are generated as owner_details, shipment_details and contact_details. Here I have one foreign key which is same for 3 rows and one unique primary key.

Now I want to print all these 3 rows on Jasper with different owner_details, shipment_details and contact_details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use three different section, one for every kind of details, you can design as follow your report.

Create a main report to get your main object (with three rows), so you can define 3 details bands with three different subreports, one for kind of detail.

In every subreport you can pass your collection and in the body of subreport you can discard the rows you don't want to print. So you'll have a report with three different sections and in every section one row. Right?

**EDIT**

To conditionate your row in detail you can do as follow (sorry but I've italian version, so the name can be different).

Select detail band as follow:

[image: Detail band selected]

In the property tab you have a field with your print condition, as follow:

[image: Property tab about detail band]

Click on 3 points and write your truly condition.

[image: Writing of print condition]

For example, if you have a field `category` with value `ship_detail` and you want to show only ship details, you can write as follow:

```
$F{category} != null && $F{category} == "ship_detail"
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but how i itearate rows on jasper and how i distinguish particular row on jasper that it should come in this band or in that band

Comment: When you create subreport, you must use a detail band. So it iterate as builtin behaviour

Comment: Thanks for your response, as per you "In every subreport you can pass your collection and in the body of subreport you can discard the rows you don't want to print.",,,    Here how can i discard particular row , i categorize columns values as ship_details, owner_details and contact_details

Comment: @sahilgarg: select your Detail band. In it's property you have a text box where you can write the print condition. you can write, for example, $F{category} == "ship_details" and so on, for each subreport where you have a detail band